# make on keyup only fire once inside of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this method:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var input = $('#search');
    input.on('keyup', function() {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) {
            console.log('ajax request cancelled');
            recentRequest.abort();
        }
    });
});
```

but as of right now everytime I press Backspace it will fire, I want to make it so it can only be fired once inside of my input. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: where would I put this?

Comment: This is confusing, backspace has the keyCode `8`, so of course it runs, what are you expecting here ?

Comment: @adeneo I want the console.log and the recentRequest.abort() to only be fired once to not reduce the server performance too much.

Comment: Then just replace `on` with `one`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `backspaceFlag` variable to ensure that backspace code is allowed/triggered only once:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var backspaceFlag = true;
  var input = $('#search');
  input.on('keyup', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && backspaceFlag) {
      backspaceFlag = false;
      console.log('ajax request cancelled');
      recentRequest.abort();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='search' />
```